# Keras Many-to-Many Classification LSTM error: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 3 [[node categorical_crossentropy/

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make a LSTM model which is capable of calculating probabilities of three classes at each time period.

I define the model in the following way:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(128,input_shape=(None,input_size)))
model.add(layers.Dense(output_size))
model.add(layers.Softmax())
model.compile(optimizer="sgd",loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())
model.fit(Generator())
```

The generator provides batches consisting of one training example *(I plan to use batches of multiple examples, but because my training examples have variable length, I keep things as simple as possible for now)*. To be more precise, the generator returns x with shape (1,T,input_size) and y with shape (1,T,3). After processing a couple of batches, keras fails with the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-51-ad3e71307f94> in <module>
      1 model.compile(optimizer="sgd",loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())
----> 2 model.fit(Generator())
      3 

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    838         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    839         # stateless function.
--> 840         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    841     else:
    842       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1841       `args` and `kwargs`.
   1842     """
-> 1843     return self._call_flat(
   1844         [t for t in nest.flatten((args, kwargs), expand_composites=True)
   1845          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1921         and executing_eagerly):
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    544         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 545           outputs = execute.execute(
    546               str(self.signature.name),
    547               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

c:\theproject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 3
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze (defined at <ipython-input-51-ad3e71307f94>:2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_16213]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Here is x and y of a sample (not the only one) batch where it fails:

```
          0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    ...  169  170  \
0    0.585963  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
1    0.831822  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
2    0.831822  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
3    0.831822  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
4    0.831822  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
..        ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   
984  0.989131  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
985  0.989927  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
986  0.990885  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
987  0.990911  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   
988  0.991843  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0   

     171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  
0    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
2    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
3    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
4    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
..   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  
984  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
985  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
986  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
987  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
988  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

> 

```
       0    1    2
0    1.0  0.0  0.0
1    1.0  0.0  0.0
2    0.0  0.0  1.0
3    1.0  0.0  0.0
4    0.0  0.0  1.0
..   ...  ...  ...
984  1.0  0.0  0.0
985  0.0  0.0  1.0
986  0.0  1.0  0.0
987  1.0  0.0  0.0
988  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Can you try sparse_categorial_crossentropy instead of categorical_crossentropy?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I did, it fails with almost identical error. + afaik sparse is used when y is an int specifying a class, not when it is an one hot vector

Comment: ah, yea just read that you are able to run a few batches and then it fails, ignore what i said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, for such kind of problem the layers after LSTM should be wrapped with TimeDistributed layer and LSTM should take argument return_sequences=True